# SQL Subquery containing OpenRowset - Syntax error - Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server

I don't see the syntax issue below.  I'm using a subquery, because I'm building it up to do a cross-apply once I get that figured out.

```
 SELECT 
   BulkColumn
   FROM
     (
      SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS xml) as BulkColumn 
            FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\Flight03.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as T
      )

Error: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
       Line # refers to the closing parenthesis at the bottom
```

The subquery, when run by itself works fine:

```
      Select CAST(BulkColumn AS xml) as BulkColumn 
            FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\Flight03.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as T
```

So shouldn't I just be able to wrap it with parentheses and use it in another query?

Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a name for your subquery. Try this:

```
SELECT 
   BulkColumn
   FROM
     (
      SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS xml) as BulkColumn 
            FROM OPENROWSET(BULK'c:\Flight03.xml',SINGLE_CLOB) as T
      ) Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

after subquery in from u must set name for it

```
select ... From (...) *name*
```